Openpyxl can't open .xlsx file after I modify it in Excel
I am trying to get tickets from Jira to modify them in Excel and update in bulk back to Jira.
I can write the data from Jira to Excel:
 # Write the DataFrame to an Excel file using openpyxl
    excel_file = "jira_tickets.xlsx"
    with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Tickets')

    print(f"Data written to {excel_file} successfully.")

I can read the .xlsx back once it is created:
# Check if the file can be opened with openpyxl
        workbook = load_workbook(file_path)
        print(f"Workbook '{file_path}' loaded successfully.")
        
        # Load the first sheet
        sheet = workbook.active
        print(f"Sheet '{sheet.title}' loaded successfully.")

However if I modify any data in the file in Excel (which I want to use for bulk editing), the read snippet above fails with:
File is not a valid Excel file or could not be read.
I validated that I can open the file in Excel (for Mac 16.89), change data, save it, reopen it, etc. but can't use openpyxl to open it.
Here is the code which checks if the file is a valid Excel file:
def is_excel_file(file_path):
    try:
        # Check if the file is a valid Excel MIME type
        mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)
        if mime_type != 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet':
            print(f"File is not a valid Excel file: {file_path}")
            return False

        # Check if the file can be opened with openpyxl
        workbook = load_workbook(file_path)
        print(f"Workbook '{file_path}' loaded successfully.")
        
        # Load the first sheet
        sheet = workbook.active
        print(f"Sheet '{sheet.title}' loaded successfully.")
        
        # Print the first few rows
        row_count = 0
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=5, values_only=True):
            print(row)
            row_count += 1
        
        if row_count == 0:
            print("No data found in the first 5 rows.")
        
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error while checking if file is a valid Excel file with openpyxl: {e}")
        return False

# Explicitly reference the filename 'jira_tickets.xlsx'
file_name = 'jira_tickets.xlsx'
if is_excel_file(file_name):
    print(f"File '{file_name}' is a valid Excel file and has been read successfully.")
else:
    print(f"File '{file_name}' is not a valid Excel file or could not be read.")

I get this error when running it:
Error while checking if file is a valid Excel file with openpyxl: File is not a zip fileFile 'jira_tickets.xlsx' is not a valid Excel file or could not be read.
Test:
- run code to read file and print a few rows (success).
- Modify file in Excel (change any cell), quit Excel
- run code to read file (fails with above messages)
- Open file in Excel again (Excel can open file, openpyxl can't open after it is modified)

A XLSX file is a bunch of zipped XML files. It can be opened by any standard zip application to view these files. When Openpyxl opens an XLSX file one of its checks to confirm the veracity of the file is whether it can be unzipped. If it cannot then its not XLSX and Openpyxl rejects it. A file may have the extension '.xlsx' and be able to be opened by Excel but it may not actually be an XLSX file, Excel itself won't necessarily show any indication that it's not. Therefore your best test for an XLSX file is to actually try to open it as a zipped file and check the underlying files if successful

Your first code using  df.to_excel absolutely will create an XLSX file which you state you can then open using load_workbook(file_path). However we don't know what happens during this section However if I modify any data in the file in Excel (which I want to use for bulk editing) So open the file in a text editor and see what it contains or what magic number it has. If you are inadvertently saving as html for example you'll see that straight away.

When I open in TextEdit, it is blank and shows locked in the title.
When I modify the data, I am just adding text to one of the text fields and saving by exiting out of Excel. I'm not manually saving to html or any other format.
What is interesting is that when I view the file in Finder, it shows a preview of the data before I modify it. After I modify it, it just shows the Excel icon. So it looks like Finder being able to preview the Excel file is an analog for openpyxl being able to read it.

Are you able to unzip he file after it is modified in Excel, ie when Openpyxl says it is not a zipped file?

MacOS doesn't treat it as a zip file before or after it is modified. It shows as a xlsx. I can zip it and unzip it of course but the inbuilt zip util in MacOS doesn't see it as a zip file

If you changed the extension to '.zip' then would MACOS treat as a zip file?

Are you sure you are using MS excel not Mac Numbers to open and modify your file? is your default app for .xlsx is indeed Excel not Numbers?
